# How does eigenvalues and eigenvectors change for $\hat{P} = \frac{1}{2}( I + P)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a square matrix $P_{nxn}$ with eigenvalues and eigenvectors, how do they change if we do $\hat{P}=\frac{1}{2}(I + P)$? where $I$ is identity matrix.
It's been a while since I've taken linear algebra, and I have a 5x5 matrix. I know I can try to solve it manually, but there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Px=\lambda x$ iff $\frac {P+I} 2 x=\frac {1+\lambda} 2 x$. So what is the conclusion?

Comment: that our new eigenvalues become $\frac{1+\lambda}{2}$. Do the eigenvectors associated with the old eigenvalues stay the same?

Comment: Yes, the eigen vectors do not change. @MinYoungKim

Comment: By deifinition . There is nothing to prove. For example if the first equation holds for some $x \neq 0$ then the second equation holds for the same vector $x$. So every eigen vector of the first matrix is an eigen vector of the second matrix. The converse is similar.

Comment: ohhh. thank you!